# About links in stackexchange.com header and footer are not consistent

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com

In http://stackexchange.com there are two `about` links, one in header and one in footer.

The link in the header links to https://stackexchange.com/about which is what expected.

However, the link in the footer links to https://stackexchange.com/about/management - is this intentional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both links now point to [/about](https://stackexchange.com/about). Thanks for the report.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the fast fix! :)