# Loading indicator is reproducing

Tags: bug, status-declined, comments

When posting comment to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89951/about-links-in-stackexchange-com-header-and-footer-are-not-consistent/90204#90204) my connection hicked up  so pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> three times produced the following:
[image]

Shouldn't the progress image be loaded in the same placeholder?

It also produced three "Comment could not be submitted" messages (due to timeout probably) which is fine.

Decline reason can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180514/152859).

Edit: as of May 21, 2013 it appears that when *editing* existing comment, there are no more loading indicators at all. They are still present when posting new comment though.

Comment: The real bug is that you pressed Enter three times in a row.

Comment: This is a test. Hmm.. still happens.

Comment: So, loading indicators are the precursor to Skynet?

Comment: @Andrew don't give them ideas!

Comment: Uh oh... too late?

Comment: No more reproducing indicator!

Comment: I had this happen to me earlier.

Comment: @Mithrandir weird, since the button is disabled when submitting.

Answer (score 3):

This has now been fixed, in a way, by having the "Add Comment" button disabled when submitting:

> [image]