# Multiple Loading Icon when click on the user search

Tags: bug, status-declined

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loading indicator is reproducing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90254/loading-indicator-is-reproducing)

I search for the one user and I get the 3 dots as loading process. When I click again its add that images again and again. Please check the screenshot attach with this question.[image: Multiple loading image]

Comment: Doesn't happen to me. Tested in FireFox/IE.

Comment: @Sid try pressing ENTER key after each letter. You will see it happening, it's the same in comments. (Each AJAX call is adding loading indicator without checking if one already exists, I already reported this in the past :))

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: Nope I still don't see it. It only happens when I press enter key multiple times successively after entering something and then it disappears automatically. Once or Twice is fine but just curious, why would one press enter key multiple times successively?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I tried on IE and I attach the screenshot too. It may be happen due to slow connection, I dont know the exact problem for this. :(

Comment: This has happened to me before somewhere else because my connection was going really, *really* slow. However, I'm completely unable to reproduce this at all on my current connection.

Comment: @Lafada: Quite possible on a slow connection. Also maybe you pressed enter key multiple times successively?