# Multiple loading bars

Tags: bug, status-declined, user-interface

In some places we can see loading indicators like user search, review question, comments, revisions etc. If we do click a number of times very fast on them multiple loading bars appear (e.g. when your internet speed is low).

Comment: Obvious answer: Stop clicking multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we know.

It is not something we will spend time fixing, as it has no real effect on usability and has an easy workaround - stop clicking multiple times.

Comment: I consider it a feature at this point...

Comment: Hey I didn't even notice you declined [my report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90254/152859) until checking it now! Well, guess you have a point.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - You win some, you lose some ;)