# Page not found while logging in

Tags: bug, status-declined, login

I accidentally clicked on signup while selecting stackexchange option on login page, results in opening of stackexchange login form as well as signup form..

When I entered my credentials to login, it threw me page not found error.

I've attached a screen below for clearing the scenario..
[image]

Steps:

1) Click on log in

2) On the log in page, click on stackexchange block, the very first one, while it's loading, instantly click on signup as well

3) Two forms will be visible on the same page, now try to log in with your valid credentials and you will see the page above..

---

Youtube Link for Video Reference - http://youtu.be/w-7I5oi-ntU

Comment: Now we also vote negative who reports bugs?

Comment: I believe people are downvoting this because they do not find it to be an actual, reproducible bug.

Comment: Why click *login* and *sign up* that close together?

Comment: This is such an edge case even if it was reproducible, and for that matter, no repro on my end (FF & IE)

Comment: Even if it is an edge case, or not reproducible, those aren't reasons to downvote a bug report - it's still a legitimate bug being reported.

Comment: I can reproduce the 2 forms, but not the "not found".

Comment: Bug fix: don't do the "while it's loading, instantly click on signup as well" part. I [learned it the hard way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90254/152859). ([decline reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180514/152859) - same logic applies in this case)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd *I **accidentally** clicked on signup while selecting*, but anyways thought to report, so I did, no harm in fixing things rather than leaving them as is :)

Comment: @Emrakul I can throw a video over here for that if you need

Comment: @Mr.Alien I was as naive as you until posting the bug report I linked to above. I'm not saying your bug won't get fixed, just there's a good chance it's too minor and too edge case to be worth fixing. (For what it's worth, I +1'd this as it's valid bug report well reported)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I just saw the link, was on phone, and thank you :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien I have+will not personally vote+d on this post, though a video might help for future visitors.

Comment: @Emrakul Shared :)

Comment: FWIW (for non-FPS gamers), the 2 forms can be reproduced by running `openid.loadSignup();openid.signin('stack_exchange');` in the console...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [Oded ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140505/oded) nicely said [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180513/multi-loading-bar-needs-edit/180514#180514):

> Yes, we know.
>
> It is not something we will spend time fixing, as it has no real effect on usability and has an easy workaround - stop clicking multiple times.