# Too many flag throbbers

Tags: bug, flags, design

**Description:**

I noticed some strange behavior when you have a *really* slow internet connection and you click the "flag" button on questions and answers more than once.

At first, a single "loading" throbber appears next to the "flag" button. But if the internet is slow, and you click the "flag" button again and again, you get this:

[image]

Whoops! We only need one, right?

This works both in and out of the review queues when flagging questions and answers.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Find somewhere with a *really* slow internet connection (or bandwidth-limit your computer).
2. Go to any question or answer.
3. Click the "flag" button.
4. Repeat Step 3.

[image]

**Solution:**

I think that the "flag" button should be greyed out once it is pressed, just like the "Save Edits" or "Post Answer" buttons. This way, users will not want to click on it again.

Also, of course, I think only one throbber should be created for the "flag" button if it is clicked.

Comment: I think the consensus here is ["don't do it"](http://i.imgur.com/Zs3xY5L.png); http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180513/multi-loading-bar-needs-edit

Comment: Well, darn. And I thought I was so original :)

Comment: You're late by three years, fellow unicorn! :D