# No badges are visible after switching from mobile web to full site

Tags: bug, badges, mobile-web, full-site

[Second page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/339911/alexolut?tab=badges&sort=name&page=2) of the my profile page with opened Badges page looks in mobile web like showed in picture:

> [image: 2ndPage]

If you make switch to full site (via link in the bottom of the page), then resulting page contains only header "24 badges", but no badges are visible:

> [image: noBadges]

This happens due different badge's count per page for mobile and web versions of the site. So in my case, page 2, saying easy, not exists for full site. Same effect could be achived by manual changing page number in the URL showed in the browser:

> meta.stackexchange.com/users/339911/alexolut?tab=badges&sort=name&**page=2**

Comment: Well, people are not really expected to switch between the views just like that, so this isn't really a "bug".

Comment: @ShadowWizard do you mean "not desired to fix bug"? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I switch views like that all the time. There are things you simply can't do in the mobile view so it's pretty necessary.

Comment: Also worth noting that it's not only badges, same thing happens on most (but not all) of the paginated activity tabs

Comment: Well, it reminds me of [this bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90254/loading-indicator-is-reproducing) - declined, there was a comment explaining it I think, something along the lines of "just don't do it". It was "fixed" on pure chance probably, as part of some redesign they made.