# Clicking on the "update user profile" link creates non-modal dialog

Tags: bug, network-profile

[Network user profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/current) contains a link named "update user profile". Clicking on that link leads to creation of new non-modal window, so I can create as many dialog boxes as I want:

> [image: choose a site]

Don't forget to scroll page or resize browser's client area to better issue observing (i.e. window created on the page center).

Same (d)effect for "my logins" link:

> [image: my logins]

I don't think that this bug should be declined as @ShadowWizard mentioned in the [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291744/clicking-on-the-update-user-profile-link-creates-non-modal-dialog?noredirect=1#comment947466_291744). In partucular for a reason that links like `share` or `flag`  below the post works much better (don't create more than one window).

Comment: umm.... just don't do it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard no repro... because I won't to click?

Comment: No, I mean it's essentially the same as [this bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90254/loading-indicator-is-reproducing) which was declined, i.e. your bug will also be declined for the same reason which is just "you are not supposed to do that". :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard post updated.

Comment: Well, let's wait for the team to decide. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard you made a typo in the word "decline" :D