# "my logins" is not loading in the network profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, my-logins

"my logins" feature does no work and UI is not displayed properly after login on so website and visiting stackexchange profile page, in my example:

https://stackexchange.com/users/159543/gibbok

In console, using chrome I get this error:

> VM147:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setCacheBreakers' of
>   undefined
>       at eval (eval at  (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:2651),
>   :3:29)
>       at eval ()
>
> [image]

If user click on "my logins" multiple times the ui is disrupted.

Comment: The "UI problem" is by design and won't be fixed, see [this similar report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90254/loading-indicator-is-reproducing) about loading indicator. As for the functionality itself it's indeed broken, hopefully they will fix it soon.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the heads up, fix just went out to production.

Comment: I checked, problem with UI it is solved. But I still see a problem, as I am not able to add a second Google Account. Please have a look here, thanks: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302270/possible-bug-adding-a-second-google-account-to-a-profile