# Possible bug, adding a second Google Account to a profile

Tags: support, bug, user-accounts

I would like to access my profile with two different Google accounts, one ending with @gmail.com the other related to Google Suite.

Currently I am doing the following:

- Visit my profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/379008/gibbok
- Login with Google account (@gmail.com).
- Click on: Network profile
- Click on: my logins
- Shows a popup "My Logins"
- Click link in popup "add more logins…"
- Visit new page (attached screenshot)
  [image]
- Click on logo "log in with Google"
- At this point I am being redirected to my profile page:
  https://stackexchange.com/users/159543/gibbok#

When instead I should be able to enter the credentials from another Google account (company one on G-Suite) I want to use.

I was able years ago to add three different accounts, but I am currently not able to add a new one.

Is a bug in the application? What are the steps to make it works?

Comment: Did you try adding it through a Q&A site (like this one) instead of on se.com? Go to your profile page, Edit profile & Settings, my logins there.

Comment: @Oded I tried on both and does not work :(

Comment: We need to make a change to the add-login process to explicitly request the account selection page at all times. Until then, the workaround is to be logged into both Google accounts you want to use.